# Python - Parsing a text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a text file with a line similar to this

```
2.000125 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  62, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto: TCP (6), length: 40, bad cksum 0 (->4100)!) 150.100.15.6.49153 > 150.100.0.2.57300: S, cksum 0x0000 (incorrect (-> 0xd43b), 0:0(0) win 65535
```

in the text file there is around 14,000 other lines. I need to be able to match 'ttl  62' with only '150.100.15' on the left side of the comparative. I'm not too sure how to do this in python, as some lines in the file also have '150.100.15' on the right side of the comparative, but I only want to parse for the ip addresses on the left side.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well, the final goal is to be able to match the correct TTL with the correct IP. And be able to also parse the ones that aren't matching when they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd do it assuming the records are separated by a colon like they seem to be in your example, it lets you pick which side of the IP to look for, and it'd be easy to change searching the ttl to something else.

Edit: this one will work with your old string but not the new one (use the bottom script for that), just leaving this here so you can potentially try learn from how it works :)

```
textfile = "tos 0x0, ttl 62, offset 0, length:40, bad cksum 0 (->4203)!) 150.100.15.6.49153 > 150.100.0.2.57300:"

ttlToSearchFor = 62
ipToSearchFor = "150.100.15"
ipSide = "right"

#Get rid of colon in the length record
lengthRename = textfile.replace( "length:", "length " )
#Split by row
individualRow = lengthRename.split( ":" )
#Loop for each record (assuming they're separated by colons)
for i in range( len( individualRow ) ):
    splitByComma = individualRow[i].split( "," )
    #Make sure the record is valid
    if len( splitByComma ) == 5:
        #Get the ttl or any other info here
        ttl = splitByComma[1].rstrip().lstrip()
        #Remove the ttl text and any spaces to leave the number
        ttlNumber = ttl.replace( "ttl", "" ).replace( " ", "" )
        if ttlNumber == str( ttlToSearchFor ):
            #Get IPs
            splitBySpace = individualRow[i].split( " " )
            rightIP  = splitBySpace[-1]
            leftIP = splitBySpace[-3]
            #Search the left or right (or both) IPs for a match
            if (ipSide == "right" and ipToSearchFor in rightIP) or (ipSide == "left" and ipToSearchFor in leftIP) or (ipSide == "both" and (ipToSearchFor in leftIP or ipToSearchFor in rightIP)):
                print individualRow[i]
                #You found the record
```

Updated it using the csv stuff from inspectorg4dget's post and your newer record, can't test it though without the file so you might need to fix one or two bits

```
ttlToSearchFor = 62
ipToSearchFor = "150.100.15"
ipSide = "right"

import csv

with open('path/to/input') as textfile:
    for row in csv.reader(textfile):
        #Make sure the record is the correct format
        if len( row ) == 10:
            #Get the ttl or any other info here
            ttl = row[1].rstrip().lstrip()
            #Remove the ttl text and any spaces to leave the number
            ttlNumber = ttl.replace( "ttl", "" ).replace( " ", "" )
            if ttlNumber == str( ttlToSearchFor ):
                #Get IPs
                splitBySpace = row[8].split( ":" )[0].split( " " )
                rightIP  = splitBySpace[-1]
                leftIP = splitBySpace[-3]
                #Search the left or right (or both) IPs for a match
                if (ipSide == "right" and ipToSearchFor in rightIP) or (ipSide == "left" and ipToSearchFor in leftIP) or (ipSide == "both" and (ipToSearchFor in leftIP or ipToSearchFor in rightIP)):
                    print row
                    #You found the record
```

Comment: I updated the code. What would I do if it the data was no longer purely separated by a comma?

Comment: The first few lines are similar to this    2.000048 arp who-has 150.100.0.2 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) tell 150.100.0.3    and     2.000048 arp reply 150.100.0.2 is-at 00:00:00:00:00:02    and the rest are in the format i posted above

Answer (score 1):

you use split and re.findall:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'tos 0x0, ttl  62, offset 0, length:40, bad cksum 0 (->4203)!)  150.100.15.6.49153 > 150.100.0.2.57300:'
>>> a=a.split('>')
>>> a
['tos 0x0, ttl  62, offset 0, length:40, bad cksum 0 (-', '4203)!) 150.100.15.6.49153 ', ' 150.100.0.2.57300:']
>>> ttl = re.findall('ttl\s+62',a[0])
>>> ttl
['ttl  62']
>>> ip = re.findall('150\.100\.15\.\d{1,3}',a[1])
>>> ip
['150.100.15.6']
>>> if ip and ttl:
...     print(ttl[0],ip[0])
... 
ttl  62 150.100.15.6
```

implementation:

```
import re
f = open('yourfile')
for a in f:
    a = a.split('>')
    ttl = re.findall('ttl\s+62',a[0])
    ip = re.findall('150\.100\.15\.\d{1,3}',a[1])
    if ip and ttl:
        print(ttl[0],ip[0])
```

Comment: What if the full line was   2.000125 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  62, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto: TCP (6), length: 40, bad cksum 0 (->4100)!) 150.100.15.6.49153 > 150.100.0.2.57300: S, cksum 0x0000 (incorrect (-> 0xd43b), 0:0(0) win 65535

Comment: @JasonWoo what's your expected output for the above input?

Comment: Regex are the right tool for this.  A little tricky for beginners to understand but powerful.  (Available in every language I've ever seen to.. not just python).  There are perhaps nicer looking ways to do this depending on how constant the line formating is that you're parsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        ttl = row[1]
        ip = row[4]
        ip = ip.split(">")[0].split()[-1]
        ip = ip.split('.')[:3]
        ip = '.'.join(ip)
        print("match:", ttl, 'with', ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this through `re` module.

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search(r'(ttl\s+\d+).*? (150\.100.15\.\d{1,3})', line.split(' > ')[0])
        if m:
            print(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2))
```